Azure App Service WebJobでPythonジョブ実行時のエラー解決方法について
Azure App Serviceのウェブジョブで、Pythonのジョブを実行したいです。
app service プランはbasicです。
OSはLinuxで、ランタイムはPythonです。 発行モデルはコードです。
簡易なPythonのスクリプトをzipファイルにしたものをアップロードしwebjobを作成しました。
作成したWebJobを実行するとエラーになります。
エラーログを見ると以下のようなメッセージが表示されてます。
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.py' with script host - 'PythonScriptHost'
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: ERR ] An error occurred trying to start process 'python.exe' with working directory '/tmp/jobs/triggered/webjobpy/bphw5fzr.pno/webjobtest'. No such file or directory
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: SYS ERR ] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred trying to start process 'python.exe' with working directory '/tmp/jobs/triggered/webjobpy/bphw5fzr.pno/webjobtest'. No such file or directory)
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred trying to start process 'python.exe' with working directory '/tmp/jobs/triggered/webjobpy/bphw5fzr.pno/webjobtest'. No such file or directory
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessWrapper.Start() in C:\wagit\AAPT-Antares-Kudu\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\ProcessWrapper.cs:line 27
  at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.Start(IProcess process, ITracer tracer, Stream output, Stream error, Stream input, IdleManager idleManager) in C:\wagit\AAPT-Antares-Kudu\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\ProcessExtensions.cs:line 242
  at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteAsync(ITracer tracer, String arguments, Stream output, Stream error, Stream input, IdleManager idleManager) in C:\wagit\AAPT-Antares-Kudu\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\Executable.cs:line 255
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer, Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String arguments, Object[] args)
  at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteReturnExitCode(ITracer tracer, Action`1 onWriteOutput, Action`1 onWriteError, String arguments, Object[] args) in C:\wagit\AAPT-Antares-Kudu\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\Executable.cs:line 165
  at Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.RunJobInstance(JobBase job, IJobLogger logger, String runId, String trigger, ITracer tracer, Int32 port) in C:\wagit\AAPT-Antares-Kudu\Kudu.Core\Jobs\BaseJobRunner.cs:line 

何か解決策はありますか？それともWebJobではpython のジョブはサポートされて無いのでしょうか？

エラーメッセージを見る限り、Windows上で起動されているように見えますが？

そうですね。そこは気になっておりました。App ServiceのOSはlinuxになっていることは確認しております。
